# Android listview click doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, click

I don't know why, but my listview stop being clickable... you know why?

```
    ListView lista_preventivi=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_preventivi);
    ArrayList<Preventivo_per_lista> preventiviLista=new ArrayList<Preventivo_per_lista>();
    // inserisco gli elementi
    db.open();
    Cursor prendi_preventivi=db.prendi_preventivi();
    while(prendi_preventivi.moveToNext()){
        String nome_preventivo=prendi_preventivi.getString(prendi_preventivi.getColumnIndex("nome"));
        String data_preventivo=prendi_preventivi.getString(prendi_preventivi.getColumnIndex("data"));
        int approvato_preventivo=Integer.parseInt(prendi_preventivi.getString(prendi_preventivi.getColumnIndex("approvato")));
        preventiviLista.add(new Preventivo_per_lista(nome_preventivo,data_preventivo,approvato_preventivo));
    }
    db.close();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    for(int i=0;i<preventiviLista.size();i++){
        Preventivo_per_lista p=preventiviLista.get(i);
        HashMap<String,Object> preventivoMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        preventivoMap.put("nome", p.getNome());
        preventivoMap.put("data", p.getData());
        if(p.getApprovato()==1){
            preventivoMap.put("approvato",true);
            preventivoMap.put("immagine",R.drawable.preventivo_si);
        }else{
            preventivoMap.put("approvato",false);
            preventivoMap.put("immagine",R.drawable.preventivo_no);
        }
        data.add(preventivoMap);
    }
    String[] from={"nome","data","approvato","immagine"};
    int[] to={R.id.nome_preventivo,R.id.data_preventivo,R.id.check_preventivo,R.id.immagine_preventivo};
    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),data,R.layout.elemento_preventivo,from,to);
    lista_preventivi.setAdapter(adapter);
    lista_preventivi.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        // click di elemento
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long _id){
            System.out.println("si");
        }
    });
```

XML

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lista_preventivi"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: blind guessing: you have some clickable element in listview row ...

Comment: Your checkbox is now clickable, it takes focus. 

P.S. Please read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html You code style is awefull. Sorry

Comment: my code is my code, and your is yours. if you think your is better, good to you.
my it's a normal code to do what i need, nothing strage.
and my checkbox have a android:clickable="false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by myself adding android:focusable="false" in the checkbox